# Are Coercions allowed within polymorphic datatypes in coq?

Tags: coq

I'm using a lot of pairs with types that would normally be coerced freely. However, the notation doesn't explicitly provide the types for the pairs, even though the context does. The following code provides a simple MWE of the principle:

```
Coercion nat_to_bool (n : nat) : bool :=
  match n with
  | 0 => false
  | _ => true
  end.

Inductive newtype : Type :=
  | firstconstr : bool -> newtype
  | secondconstr : (bool * bool) -> newtype.

Check (3 : bool).
Check (firstconstr 3).
Fail Check (secondconstr (3, true)).
Check (secondconstr (@pair bool bool 3 true)).
```

The failure message is `The term "(3, true)" has type "(nat * bool)%type" while it is expected to have type "(bool * bool)%type".` Obviously the type system can figure out the type that it is supposed to be, but can't decide to coerce the value properly.

Is there a way to declare the coercion in such a way that tuples (and other polymorphic data types with inferred types) are coerced properly?

Comment: For clarification on what this will be used with: I have notation for `x : T` declared to be a pair, and `Gamma |- p` declared as `(types Gamma pair)`. If x is a variable name, it should be automatically converted to a value; but due to the lack of coercion, I've had to sprinkle a lot of function application into the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can make a notation that desugars to an annotation so the coercion goes through, assuming the pair is always constructed explicitly (that seems fair for a typing judgement `G |- x : T` where `x : T` is a pair, although I think the whole judgement is more commonly seen as a triple).

Here's a PoC with the minimal example:

```
Notation "'secondconstr'' ( x , y )" := (secondconstr (x : bool, y)).

Check (secondconstr' (3, true)).
```

And in the context of your `types` judgement, it might look like this:

```
Notation "Gamma |- v : T" := (types Gamma (v : value, T))
  (at level 100).
```